# How to give a string as input to cut command in perl

Tags: perl

I have a string say 
`my $str = "Hello Hi Bye"`, and I want supply this string to cut command get the fields.
Can anyone please help me how to do this?

And what about this? I was actually trying to do like this...I have an array:

`my @str  = ("hello hi bye","hello hi you","abc def ghi","abc def jkl");`

I want to provide this array to cut the first two fields and get the unique one among them.
Like output should be `"hello hi"` and `"abc def"` and get the count of such unique combination of those 2 fields, here it is 2..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = "Hello Hi Bye";
my @fields = split /\s+/, $str;
```

Whenever you want "unique", think "hash":

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my %count;
my @str = ("hello hi bye","hello hi you","abc def ghi","abc def jkl"); 
for (@str) {
    my @flds = (split)[0..1];
    $count{"@flds"}++;
}
print Dumper(\%count);

__END__

$VAR1 = {
          'abc def' => 2,
          'hello hi' => 2
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`split` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
my $str = "Hello Hi Bye";
my @fields = split(/\s+/, $str); # => ('Hello', 'Hi', 'Bye')
```